# How to solve Google translate api 404 error

Tags: google-translation-api

Iam using Google translate api to translate an email body.Billing is added to the api key as well.
Iam getting 404-not found error when i make an api call.

```
        var apiKey = "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$";
         var endpoints = {
      translate: "",
      detect: "detect",
      languages: "languages"
    };
      function makeApiRequest(endpoint, data, type, authNeeded) {
            url = "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/"+ endpoint;
      url += "?key=" + apiKey;

      // If not listing languages, send text to translate
      if (endpoint !== endpoints.languages && endpoint !== endpoints.detect) 
{
        url += "&q=" + encodeURI(data.textToTranslate1);
        url +=  "&q=" + encodeURI(data.textToTranslate2);
      }
     if (endpoint === endpoints.detect) {
        url += "&q=" + encodeURI(data.textToTranslate1);
      }

      // If translating, send target and source languages
      if (endpoint === endpoints.translate) {
        url += "&target=" + data.targetLang;
        url += "&source=" + data.sourceLang;
        url+="&format=text";
      }
     jQuery.support.cors = true;
      // Return response from API
      return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type || "GET",
        data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : "",
        dataType: "JSON",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Accept: "application/json"
        }
      });
}

function translate(data) {
      makeApiRequest(endpoints.translate, data, 
  "GET",false).success(function(resp) {

 //the code
 });
  .on("click", "button.translate", function() {
          var translationObj = {};
          translationObj = {
            sourceLang: $(".source-lang").val(),
            targetLang: $(".target-lang").val(),
            textToTranslate1: "Good Morning",
            textToTranslate2: "Good Night"
          };

            translate(translationObj);
}
```

This is the api request code iam using.
**Once I clear cache and reload the application for 5-6 times,only then the api gives response..**

Can you please help me here

Answer (score 0):

[Docs say](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors#error_localization): 404  NOT_FOUND   A specified resource is not found, or the request is rejected by undisclosed reasons, such as whitelisting.

I think this line could be wrong: url = "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/"+ endpoint;

as you are adding additional text that makes the endpoint different to the one expected. Quoted text should be enough according [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/translate).

The line that adds the api key seems to be correct:  url += "?key=" + apiKey;

Answer (score 0):

The google translate API has conflict with mootools, please turn off mootools if you use it